# Error to launch winghci shipped in haskell platform package 2012.2.0.0

Tags: haskell, winghci

Everytime I double click winghci.exe an error message `CreateGHCiProcess failed with failed with error 2` pops. I assume the installation hasn't completed setting environment variables successfully since cmd `C:\>ghci` ends up with no command found either. Could anyone help posting changes that might take place during the installation or any solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete the incomplete answer: add the path of the bin directory inside your haskell platform folder, e.g. C:\Programs\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin, to your PATH. That should be all.

Answer (score 1):

Issue closed. Solution is to set $PATH$ by either reinstallation or manual

Answer (score 0):

I think that's supposed to be %PATH% when you're dealing with windows.

`path = c:\programs\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin;%path%` for your example.You could also make a shortcut and point the "Start in:" entry at where you've installed the bin directory.For me, I have it installed under "c:\users[ME]\my documents\dev\Haskell Playform\2013.2.0.0\bin"Starts up fine.